# Why cant my network send packages but piv6 pings go through?

Tags: routing, ipv6, packet-tracer

I have the following network:
[image]

My routing is as follows:
[image]

```
Device configuration for ISP:
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1388 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname ISP
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524G9I3-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:18::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:19::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ipv6 router eigrp 1
 eigrp router-id 1.1.1.1
 no shutdown 
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Running config of R1:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1481 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524FM8R-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 ipv6 address FE80::3 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1E::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::3 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1F::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::3 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ipv6 router eigrp 1
 eigrp router-id 3.3.3.3
 no shutdown 
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Running configuration of R2:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1515 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524M58A-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1A::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1B::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1C::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1D::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface Serial0/2/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ipv6 router eigrp 1
 eigrp router-id 2.2.2.2
 no shutdown 
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Running configuration of R3:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1465 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX15244N50-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 ipv6 address FE80::4 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:21::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::4 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:22::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::4 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:23::1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 1
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/2/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ipv6 router eigrp 1
 eigrp router-id 4.4.4.4
 no shutdown 
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

I used eigrp for my routing. I can send pings from computer to computer just fine but when I try to send a package from packet tracer it doesn't reach anywhere, not even in the same address. why? and how do I fix it? you can toy with my project through this link

https://www.mediafire.com/file/bo3cdoafvlky0s1/ejercicio_3.pkt/file

Comment: The actual device configurations would need to be posted to provide useful feedback.

Comment: Please provide configurations, people often do not have Packet Tracer and/or are not willing to download files from a random website just to help you.

Comment: @TeunVink There, I added what I could. hope this is enough to get my question back